# Integrating ServiceNow for Agent Transfer: How to Create Chats from External Systems?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, servicenow-client-scripts

I have a specific use case where I need to integrate my system with ServiceNow to create chats on behalf of users and receive agents' messages.

After researching, I came across the AWA module in ServiceNow, which allows transferring chats to agents using queues. Additionally, ServiceNow offers several base channels like chat, incidents, etc., enabling users to create work items for agents. However, I am facing challenges in figuring out how to create chats from an external system, possibly utilizing APIs. My main objective is to assign these chats to agents and receive messages back to my system for responding to users.

The goal of this integration is to leverage ServiceNow for agent transfer exclusively, while managing chat interactions externally. Any insights, guidance, or code examples on how to achieve this chat creation and agent message reception through APIs would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!